# Increase StrokeThickness but maintain dimensions of Path

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, geometry

I have a `Path` that normally has a StrokeThickness of 1. Under certain circumstances, it needs to have a StrokeThickness of 10. When I increase the stroke thickness, I don't want the path to take any additional space.

By default, just increasing the StrokeThickness increases the rendered size of the path. So you get something like this (the blue outline extends beyond the black boundary):

[image: Stroke expands beyond original boundary of path]

This is what I'm trying to achieve (the blue outline stays within the black boundary):

[image: Stroke is entirely inside original boundary of path]

I can think of two mathematical ways to compensate for the increased StrokeWidth:

1. Manually adjust the points of the triangle inward.
2. Use a ScaleTransform on the Geometry of the Path.

Both of these would be somewhat problematic/complex. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could clip the path by its own geometry like this:

```
<Path ... Clip="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

but then you would need to double the StrokeThickness, since only half of the stroke is visible.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, what if I need opposite? to keep only the outer stroke, is there a way to exclude the self geometry?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563157/clip-inverted-own-geometry

Answer (score 0):

On a whim I set **StrokeThickness = -1** on my Rectangle and it did exactly what I wanted it to: the stroke goes on the *inside* of the Rectangle rather than on the outside.

Comment: So to solve the OP's specific case, it should be varied between -1 and -10?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. StrokeThickness of -1 and 1 give the same result for me