# Shape with inner stroke

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

By default, adding a `Stroke` to a `Shape` in WPF / WinRT XAML creates an outline that is centered around the edges, meaning that half of the outline is outside the shape. But I need to create a shape with stroke und no fill that has the same silhouette as the shape with fill and no stroke. Is there an easy way to change the stroke so that the whole outline is inside?

I could create an OpacityMask that covers the inverted shape, but OpacityMasks are not supported in WinRT XAML. I could also create a smaller shape via inward polygon buffering ([An algorithm for inflating/deflating (offsetting, buffering) polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109536/an-algorithm-for-inflating-deflating-offsetting-buffering-polygons)), but I was hoping for a simpler solution, e.g. a simple property to change the stroke to "inside".

Comment: It would be simpler to set the `Clip` property instead of `OpacityMask` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10594612/1136211), but unfortunately that would also not work in WinRT, as `Clip` can only be a `RectangleGeometry`.

Comment: @Sebastian Negraszus I have the same problem.Any updates?

Comment: @Abin: No updates. I'm not working on this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I've really been trying to come up with an answer to this one. Over and over every attempt has some type of limitation. I'm afraid the answer is, you cannot do this - not with dynamic vectors at least. You can always create an image to simulate it. But that sucks.