# Clip inverted own geometry

Tags: wpf, xaml, geometry

Following [Increase StrokeThickness but maintain dimensions of Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594315/increase-strokethickness-but-maintain-dimensions-of-path), is it possible to do the opposite? keeping only the outer stroke. Is there a way to exclude the self geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also clip the Path by its own geometry, but use a `CombinedGeometry` with a large enough outer RectangleGeometry and an excluded inner geometry, provided by the Path's `Data`:

```
<Path ...>
    <Path.Clip>
        <CombinedGeometry
            GeometryCombineMode="Exclude"
            Geometry2="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Path}}">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="-1000,-1000,2000,2000"/>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Clip>
</Path>
```

Alternatively, you may perhaps draw a second, filled Path with the same geometry on top of the first one. You need to make sure both are aligned identically.

```
<Path x:Name="path" ...>
<Path Fill="White" Data="{Binding Data, ElementName=path}"/>
```

Comment: The first thing that happened is that I had to start adding zeros to make the rectangle larger to meet every possible scenario (zooming etc) :) Is there a better hack than a "large enough" RectangleGeometry?

Comment: See the alternative.