# How do you get a Path object to stop clipping to its bounds?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hopefully I'm missing something simple here.  I'm trying to draw arrow geometry using a `Path` shape in my XAML.  However, since some of my lines go right to the edges of the bounding box, plus it having a thick stroke (made thicker for this demo) they are getting clipped.

I have tried setting `ClipToBounds` to false, but it doesn't have any effect.

Here's the relevant XAML. I've added coloring and a margin to show what it's doing..

```xml
<Border Background="LightGreen">

    <Path
        Margin="10" ClipToBounds="False"
        Width="100"
        Height="40"
        Data="M0,20 L20,0 L20,12 L100,12 L100,28 L20,28 L20,40z"
        Fill="Yellow"
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="4" />

</Border>
```

And here's the results...

[image]

So how do you stop a `Path` shape from clipping?

Comment: `<Path Stretch="Uniform" .../>`. Or just don't set its Width and Height.

Comment: Not quite!  That results in the path being reduced to within the bounds, which does result in it being visible entirely, but now the graphics aren't aligned with where they need to be because they are shrunken down.

Comment: `Stretch="Fill"` may also work. In general, don't set Width and Height with Stretch=None.

Comment: That too results in the geometry being shrunken to within the bounds, but this time it's distorted.  I'm actually playing with artificially offsetting the geometry by 10,10, increasing the width and height by 20, then putting negative 10 margins around the outside.  That way it uses the layout system to avoid the clipping.  It's a cheat, but it may work.

Comment: As said, just don't set Width and Height. Or at least set large enough values that allow the "outer" half of the stroke being drawn. Use 60 and 120, add 10 to all coordinates and remove the margin.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  It doesn't work.  When you set `Stretch` to either `Fill` or `Uniform`, it shrinks the geometry to fit within the bounds.  That isn't the same as not clipping because now the geometry is in a different location.  That's the issue. You can try it by removing `Margin="10"` in my code above.  What *should* happen is the black border at the right end should straddle half inside the green area and half outside of the green area because the line runs exactly along the green edge, but that doesn't happen.  It looks like my negative-margins trick however will work.

Comment: My last recommendation was meant to be done with Stretch=None.

Comment: I think you and I came to the same conclusion.  Utilize negative margins to compensate for positive offsets when drawing.  (BTW, the 10 margin here was just for illustrative purposes. In the actual code, it's zero (or 'negative offset' if you will.) Still, it's a shame that there's a property 'ClipToBounds' that's essentially ignored.  I even tried reflection to get at `VisualClip` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd generate this display is to use the container (in your case the border) to control the size of the graphic, and then define the `Path` with `Stretch="Fill"` to use as much of the available space as appropriate. That way you can specify the `Path's` `Data` value using it's own nominal coordinate system, rather than calculating the exact pixel location for each vertex of the path.

```
<Border Background="LightGreen" Width="140" Height="60">
    <Path
        Margin="10"
        Data="M 0,3 L 3,0 `L 3,2 L 10,2 L 10,4 L 3,4 L 3,6 z"
        Fill="Yellow"
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeThickness="4" 
        Stretch="Fill" />
</Border>
```

[image: arrow]

Comment: Interesting!  However, this messes up the actual graphic alignment since it's stretching the geometry so the coordinates don't line up to where I need them to. I did try `Uniform`, which removed the distortion, but still doesn't line the points up with where they need to be because that reduces the size to within the bounds.  So odd!

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe I tend to create my graphical items by specifying the inner and outer edge to define a shape rather than using the path's stroke so there's never an issue getting things to line up. See my blog post http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-xaml-icon-host/ for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I usually do exactly that myself.  But in this case, we have to use the stroke.  BUT... I think I have a work-around... draw the graphics offset by 10,10, increase the width and height by 20 (this is essentially *drawing* a margin of 10), then applying a negative-10 margin to the path.  That way technically the graphics aren't clipped. The layout compensates for the final positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not exactly what I was afer (because I wanted the graphic to extend outside of the bounds) but a sort-of workaround [was found here on S/O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594612/168179):

You clip the path by its own geometry, then you double the stroke thickness, like so:

```xml
<Path
    Margin="10" ClipToBounds="False"
    Width="100"
    Height="40"
    Data="M0,20 L20,0 L20,12 L100,12 L100,28 L20,28 L20,40z"
    Clip="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Fill="Yellow"
    Stroke="Black"
    StrokeThickness="8" />      <-- Doubled the thickness here
```

Notice how I had to double the `StrokeThickness` from 4 to 8.

The downside of this approach is you can only use it for closed paths that mark the bounds of your geometry. For instance, I couldn't draw a horizontal line down the center as part of the same geometry or it would be stroked at the full thickness of eight, not four, so you'll have to layer two different Path objects if you need such an effect.

I'm going to leave this as unanswered for a few more days in case someone does figure out how to disable clipping, but at least this is a semi-viable work-around for now.